# How to update values in my DB with new values from <select> and <input> tags?

Tags: php, html, mysql

With this way, I get results from database and "print" them. But I don't know how I will update those results when I press the submit button!!! I just need an idea or something for the next step. Thank you in advance!!!

Here is an example of my code...

```
<?php // DATABASE QUERY
      $query="SELECT countdown_module, hometeam_position
                FROM jos_gm_nextmatch
               WHERE id = 1";
      $result=mysql_query($query);

      // DATABASE VARIABLES
      $countdown_module = mysql_result($result,$i,"countdown_module");
      $hometeam_position = mysql_result($result,$i,"hometeam_position"); ?>

<form action="***.php" method="post" name="form">

<input name="countdown_module" value="<?php echo $countdown_module ?>" type="text" />

<select name="hometeam_position">
<option value="<?php echo $hometeam_position ?>"><?php echo $hometeam_position ?></option>
<option disabled="disabled" value="...">...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">3</option>
<option value="5">5</option>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="UPDATE" />

</form>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What is the problem if I keep mysql_*??? My whole site is working like this. And it's Joomla 1.5. Can you explain please? I really want to know.

Comment: Please read the links associated with the comment.

Comment: OK I got it. let's say I will change my custom codes from mysql to mysqli... What about my site that is Joomla 1.5 version??? Will I have problem with it's default db calls??? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Like I said, don't use `mysql_*` in *new* code. When you start a new project from now on, don't use them. If you have a large project already running, you shouldn't modify your existing code unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the form action to redirect to a script where you do the update. On this script you can access the the forms input elements by using the $_POST array. As for how to do update queries, an example could be:

```
$query="UPDATE mytable 
        SET title = '".$title."', name = '".$name."', date = '".$date."' 
        WHERE id = ".$id;
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

UPDATE:

An example of the script could be:

```
$hometeam_position = $_POST['hometeam_position']; //access the selected option when submitting
$countdown_module = $_POST['countdown_module']; //access the text input

$query = "UPDATE jos_gm_nextmatch SET countdown_module = '".$countdown_module."', hometeam_position = '".$hometeam_position."' WHERE id = 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I made like this, before `SELECT` in same page:
`if (isset($_POST['submit']) or isset($_GET['submit'])){
 $stmt = "UPDATE jos_gm_nextmatch
             SET countdown_module = '".$_POST["countdown_module"]."'
           WHERE id=1";
 mysql_query($stmt);}` and I set form action to it self. So every time I click submit it updates!!! Thank you very much for your time my friend!!!

Comment: You're very welcome, thanks for my first accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could before or after selecting the fields from the database simply increment them

```
...
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = "UPDATE jos_gm_nextmatch
             SET countdown_module = " . $_POST['countdown_module'] .
           " , hometeam_position =" . $_POST['hometeam_position'] . 
           " WHERE id=1";
    mysql_query($stmt);
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: @DNA180 you are right. Of cause you have to check, if the submit button was pressed. Now it should work.

Comment: Now it adds +1 to my values every time I click submit button lol... I don't want to do something like this my friend!!!

Comment: Actually you are right, I thought you want to increment the values when submitting the form, but you wanted an idea, when to make your update.

Comment: @tadman Yes we all know it, and we should use PDO instead of mysql_query, since we could change the database etc..  This was to point out where the problem is right?