# How to update values in my DB with values from <select> tags - (Not $_POST)

Tags: php, database, joomla, joomla1.5

I want to take values from `<select>` or `<input>` **tags** but using **function** `onclick` button, not using `$_POST`. I did a try but I have stack on syntax. In case of `$_POST` goes like this:

**The button in to my form:**

```
<input class="" name="submit" type="submit" value="UPDATE" />
```

**My update query:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) or isset($_GET['submit'])){
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "UPDATE table
             SET name = '".$_POST["name"]."',
                 lastname = '".$_POST["lastname"]."',
                 rank = '".$_POST["rank"]."'
           WHERE id=1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();}
```

Now I am trying to do something like this:

**The button in to my form:**

```
<input class="" name="submit" type="submit" value="UPDATE" onclick="update()" />
```

**My update query:**

```
function update(){
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "UPDATE table
             SET name = ???,
                 lastname = ???,
                 rank = ???
           WHERE id=1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();}
```

But what is the syntax to call `<select>` and `<input>` tags names? Or their values in other words.

Comment: You do realize that `onclick="update()"` refers to a JAVASCRIPT function named update and not a PHP function of that name right?  If you want to POST data to your server without an actual form POST, you really need to read up on AJAX.

Comment: The `onclick` is a JavaScript action which is run in the Browser. You can't reasonably expect the Browser to execute code on the server without using AJAX.

Comment: I'd suggest you google javascript tutorial and look at jQuery's `on()` function instead of relying on the `onclick` event.

Comment: OK guys I got it. Thank you very much for your answers!!! They were very helpful!!! I'll do as hafichuk said.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing the code that runs on the client-side (JS) with the code that runs on the server-side (PHP). JS runs after the PHP finished - so you can't "call" from JS to functions in PHP unless you submit a form (POST/GET) or use AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

TYou must use $.ajax if you want to do this just by clicking a button and not refreshing or redirecting your browser

1) Read about http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

2) add an eventhandler on your button onclick="update();"

3) create an ajax thingy like:

```
function request(variable1,variable2,variable3){

        var request = $.ajax({
          url: "/server.php", // The address of you php script that will handle the request 
          type: "POST", // Method type GET / POST in this case POST (Similar to form submission methods....)
          data: { // What you send to the server 'VariableName' : VariableValue, in this case you assign the varaiables that were passed to the request function.
                'var1': variable1,
                'var2' : variable2,
                'var3': variable3
                },
          dataType: "json" // The response type you expect from the server
        })

        request.done(function(msg) // Function being called when everything is ok and server sends back data
        {
             console.log(msg) // handle the reply / data
        })

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) // Something went wrong...
        {
            console.log(textStatus); // See the error report
            console.log(jqXHR);
        })

        request.complete(function(){
            console.log("Ajax request complete!"); // This will always be executed when a request has completed even if it failed. (Executes after .done and .fail)
        })


}
```

So you cound do this inside your update function that is being called whenever you click the button:

```
function update()
{
 var val1 = $.('#selectbox').val();
 var val2 = $.('#inputbox').val();
 var val3 = $.('#textarea').val();

 new request(val1,val2,val3);

}
```

The request / variables will be sent using the POST method so in you php script 
you may process them as you would do with a form

```
if(isset($_POST['var1']) && isset($_POST['var2']) && isset($_POST['var3']))
{
   $serverReply = doThings($_POST['var1'],$_POST['var2'],$_POST['var3']);

   //and this is how you reply to your client/browser in json format

   echo json_encode($serverReply);
}
```

Make sure to Check more in Depth tutorials regarding ajax comunication.
There are plenty around on the net.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the URL!!! They are really helpful. But as I see at the last part of your example, I have to use `$_POST` anyway!!! Right?

Comment: Well you could use $_REQUEST more info here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php but I dont think this is a limit to you. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Ela re patrioti, tora proseksa to onoma sou... Hahaha!!! Someone, here in stackoverflow, told me not to use `$_POST` because it is dangerous for my site generally. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347217/how-can-i-update-two-tables-in-one-query#comment19968947_14347217) is the conversations, take a look at the comments. Maybe I misunderstood something, who knows. My English isn't the best anyway!!!

Answer (score 1):

onclick called function javascript

function javascript implements with ajax

example:

```
$("#submitButtonId").click(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```